# Custom touch keyboard in Windows RT

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

Is it possible to change something in the touch keyboard in Windows RT?
For example, my app is a massive data entry. Many fields are alphanumeric IDs.
It is a mess to change all time from the numeric (123 key) to letter keyboard.

Is there a way to define which keys are included or excluded?

I used InputScope but it is very limited and no way to put numbers and letters in the same screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm Sorry, it is not possible to replace the touch keyboard on Modern UI in WinRT, without cracking.

[Microsoft Windows RT Forum Hardware](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_rt-hardware/msklc-custom-keyboard-layouts-on-windows-rt/48e89275-988c-41e0-994a-7588dfb0d432)

Comment: Is this still the case with Windows 8.1?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `InputScope` of your `TextBox` control to indicate what type of keyboard you would like for that text box. That's the best you can do. There is no facility for defining custom keyboard layouts in an application. (Keyboard layouts are considered a language feature, not an app feature.)